# Google My Business API has not been used in project {projectNumber}

Tags: php, google-api, google-client, google-my-business-api

I try implemented Google Client for download all reviews of my business place.

But I still get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Google My Business API has not been used in project number before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=number then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Google My Business API has not been used in project number before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=number then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=number"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "mybusiness.googleapis.com",
          "consumer": "projects/number"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mybusiness.googleapis.com/overview?project=******* I get error

```
Failed to load.
There was an error while loading /apis/library/mybusiness.googleapis.com?project=****. Please try again.
```

My code:

```
public function renderDownloadGoogleReviews()
{
    /**Create client**/
    $client = $this->getClient();
    /**MyBusiness**/
    $myBusiness = new Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
    $accounts = $myBusiness->accounts;
    $accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
    dump($accountsList);
    die();
}
    
public function renderRedirectUri()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('**Project Name**');
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage']);
    $client->setAuthConfig(self::CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $authCode = $this->getParameter('code');
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if (!file_exists(dirname(self::TOKEN_PATH))) {
        if (!mkdir($concurrentDirectory = dirname(self::TOKEN_PATH), 0700, true) && !is_dir($concurrentDirectory)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Directory "%s" was not created', $concurrentDirectory));
        }
    }
    file_put_contents(self::TOKEN_PATH, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", self::TOKEN_PATH);
}

private function getClient(): Client
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('**ProjectName**');
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage']);
    $client->setAuthConfig(self::CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    if (file_exists(self::TOKEN_PATH)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::TOKEN_PATH), true);
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        echo "<a href='$authUrl'>$authUrl</a>";
        die();
    }

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents(self::CREDENTIALS_PATH, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }    
    return $client;
}
```

In Google console I have added:

- My Business Account Management API
- My Business Business Calls API
- My Business Business Information API
- My Business Lodging API
- My Business Notifications API
- My Business Place Actions API
- My Business Q&A API
- My Business Verifications API

Please can you tell me where I made mistake?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Reviews are currently only available through a 9th API that you have not enabled:

The [Google My Business API v4.9](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest).

Comment: I can't see that 9th API in the Google Console API Marketplace, where can I enable it? @vpriesner

Comment: Try this form to get access to the private GMB API: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdoCw8P5JJsJ-taCH2i8w8B69sGsZfoRhacQOe7FTWArWZ-SQ/viewform

Comment: If that does not help, try contacting API support via this form: https://support.google.com/business/contact/api_default

Comment: I filled in the form, thanks. Google docs are so cumbersome sometimes, it is really hard to find the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request access to their Google MyBusiness API as stated in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access

[image]

Here is the link to the form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XTQc-QEjsE7YrgstyJxbFDnwmhUhBFFvpNJBw3VzuuE/viewform